# OnItemclick loosing value of string

Tags: android, string, final, onitemclick

Good day everyone.

Unfortunately i don't have much experience with java and i run into a probably very basic issue. I am filling a list view and when i click one of the list items i want to send a string to another intent. but the value of the string is always the same even tough it show up correctly in the list view. I guess it has to do with the String getting overwritten every time a new item appears.

I want parts[3] to be send to another function in the onItemClick how would i accomplish that?

**Here is the code**

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        try {
            ViewHolder holder;
            final String uuidbeacon;
            final String pid;
            uuidbeacon = arrayL.get(position).getProximityUuid().toString();
            minorbeacon = arrayL.get(position).getMinor();
            rangebeacon = arrayL.get(position).getAccuracy();
            parts = fetchTums(uuidbeacon).split("::");

            if (convertView != null) {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            else{

                if(parts[0].equals("1")) {
                    holder = new ViewHolder(convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tupple_monitoring, null));
                    holder.beacon_image.setImageDrawable(getTumImage("http://127.0.0.1/uploads/face/" + parts[4]));
                    holder.beacon_uuid.setText(parts[1]);
                    holder.beacon_txpower.setText(parts[3]);

                    if(parts[2].equals("1"))
                    {
                        holder.beacon_row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#B6B6B6"));
                        holder.image_lock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
                if(parts[0].equals("0"))
                {
                    holder = new ViewHolder(convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tupple_monitoringe, null));

                }
            }
            pid = parts[3];
            if (arrayL.get(position).getProximityUuid() != null)



            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id )
                {
                    //list.setItemChecked(position, true);
                    //view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    toastThis(pid);
                   if(parts[2].equals("1")){

                       pin(pid);
                   }
                   else{
                        if(pid != null){
                            openPage(parts[3], "", parts[1]);
                        }
                   }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: You are not picking the value using position provided in `onItemClick`

Comment: @JibranKhan How would i accomplish that?

Comment: Get the value using position as an index of your data provider.

Comment: For instance if its an array you will get the value like this `array[position];`

Comment: @JibranKhan So if i understand you correctly i should make pid a array and then get it with pid[position]?

Comment: What is your source of data, how are you populating the listview ?

Comment: @JibranKhan My source of data is a database i query the database with fetchtums and it returns a string like this 1::0::name::some more values::etc and i split that string into parts.

Comment: From your code its parts which is supplying the data so you will get like this parts[position];

Comment: @JibranKhan That is what i tried parts[3] is the id from my database witch i want to send to another intent in open page. but parts[3] is always the value of the last row in my list view.

Comment: Sorry its arrayL i guess from which you have to get the complete value

Comment: using arrayL, am i right ?

Comment: @JibranKhan yup you were right using arrayL

Comment: glad to know. Putting it as an answer so others can have help from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pick the value using the `position` received from `onItemClick` to get exact item clicked. In your case you will have to get the value at index (position) in your `arrayL` like below.

`String item = arrayL[position];`

Answer (score 0):

I would try to implement the click listener outside of your adapter. For instance, inside a Fragment.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(getActivity(), mItems);
    ListView list       = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_list_id);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClicked());
}


private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClicked() {
    return new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
            YourItem item = (YourItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(i);
            // your magic happens here
        }
    };
}
```